# How are the eigenvalues of A related to a matrix B where

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

1. $B = A^n $        where, $n = 1, 2,\dots$ (note that this is a matrix power, not element-wise powers)
2. $B = \alpha  A$         where, $\alpha$  is a scalar
3. $B = A + \alpha I$   where, $\alpha$ is a scalar

---

[image]

Comment: Show your efforts (what you tried) and where you got stuck.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Copying the problem and pasting it here is not appropriate for who wants to know and learn.